# Error in importing "asammdf" in Python 3.5

Tags: python

I am trying to import asammdf to read MDF files but when i excute my script, there is an error from first line " import asammdf"

error is as follows :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in

```
import asammdf
```

File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\asammdf_*init*_.py", line 15, in

```
from .blocks.mdf_v2 import MDF2
```

File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v2.py", line 4, in

```
from .mdf_v3 import MDF3
```

File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v3.py", line 455

```
types.append(("", f"V{gap}"))

                          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

The library is using f-strings (see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)), which were implemented in Python 3.6:

```
f"V{gap}"
```

But you are running this in Python 3.5:

```
File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v3.py", line 455
```

You should install a newer version of Python. Python 3.5 is not supported any more (it is at end of life - see [status of python branches](https://devguide.python.org#status-of-python-branches)).

Answer (score 0):

Both github repo and the pypi page state that for version 5.x.y of asammdf the minimum python version is 3.6

You probably just copied the package manually to the site-packages folder